# Interior of a set $A$ is dense in $X$ iff $A$ is dense in $X$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I would like to check if the following statement is true:

> Interior of a set $A$ is dense in $X$ iff $A$ is dense in $X$

It seems to me that they are equivalent, but I couldn't prove or find a counterexample for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb  Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ but interior of $\mathbb Q$ is empty.

Comment: Thanks! But does the other direction holds? Int A is dense $\Rightarrow$ A is dense?

Comment: Yes, the other direction is trivial. Interior A is already dense and included in A, so...

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, another example is that the irrationals ${\mathbb R}\setminus{\mathbb Q}$ are dense in $\mathbb R$ but have empty interior.